# Difference between "Archival record" and "Archive reference"

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

How should an official document containing information about exams passed by a person in previous years be called? Are there any differences between "Archival record" and "Archive reference" in the context of this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An official document in such a case would be called a record. A reference can be any document or other artifact to which one refer as a source of information. The difference is the "official" nature of the document. One can use an official record as a reference in writing a book, say, but a reference does not have to be an official record of something.

Answer (score 0):

A question from Ukraine. 
If I want to get a document from official archive with a signature of the archive about my previous job.( This isformation is kept in the archive. They don' give me a copy of the document, they just print a document, comfirming that I did workwd in a sertain organization (the information os based on the archvival document
Thanks

Victoria

Comment: Hi, Victoria, how does this post answer the question? You have a few typos (sertain, os, a period before Thanks) and what's **A question from Ukraine** have to do with the answer? Can you edit your post?